# import json using box2d , I do not see the imported object

Tags: java, json, libgdx, box2d, physics-engine

I have a problem with the rendering of a json object created with Box2D Editor .
My problem is that even if the object septum (correctly according to the tutorial found online ) , it is not seen on the stage.

```
private void createBottle() {
    // 0. Create a loader for the file saved from the editor.
    BodyEditorLoader loader = new BodyEditorLoader(Gdx.files.internal("ball.json"));

    // 1. Create a BodyDef, as usual.
    BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
    bd.position.set(spaceShip.getX(), spaceShip.getY());
    bd.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

    // 2. Create a FixtureDef, as usual.
    FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
    fd.density = 1;
    fd.friction = 0.5f;
    fd.restitution = 0.3f;

    // 3. Create a Body, as usual.
    bottleModel = world.createBody(bd);

    // 4. Create the body fixture automatically by using the loader.
    loader.attachFixture(bottleModel, "test01", fd, 8);

}
```

In the create method i have this:

```
createBottle();
```

in the Render method:

```
Vector2 bottlePos = bottleModel.getPosition().sub(bottleModelOrigin);
bottleSprite.setPosition(bottlePos.x, bottlePos.y);
bottleSprite.setOrigin(bottleModelOrigin.x, bottleModelOrigin.y);
bottleSprite.setRotation(bottleModel.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
bottleSprite.draw(batch);
```

I do not understand why it is not added , I can not see on the screen .... I have other items assigned with the z position ... but nothing does not want to appear .

My goal is to enter the mazes made ​​with box2d editor and will move into a commanding object with a virtual joystick , this is the game I'm doing ...

if someone wants to enlighten me on how to import successfully , it is the first time you use an external editor with import json .

EDIT
[image]

I tried to follow the tutorial also before posting my question here on .
However the error is on Vector2 .... also the tutorial is clear but not working ... even online I saw other examples that they said that did not work ... there is not a resource running around? I have not found yet

Answer (score 0):

You might try as it is stated here  [here](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/):

LibGDX draws images with a reference to their bottom left corner. Therefore, if you left the reference point at the bottom left corner of your body, you can directly place the image at the location of the reference point (returned by Box2d engine with the getPosition() method).Else, if you changed the reference point location, you need to take it into account to draw the image.

Therefore, you need to store the reference point somewhere for later use:

```
bottleModelOrigin = loader.getOrigin("test01", BOTTLE_WIDTH).cpy();
```

Finally, in your render method, you can draw the image at the reference point location, offset by its local coordinates relatively to the image bottom left corner:

```
public void render() {
Vector2 bottlePos = bottleModel.getPosition().sub(bottleModelOrigin);

bottleSprite.setPosition(bottlePos.x, bottlePos.y);
bottleSprite.setOrigin(bottleModelOrigin.x, bottleModelOrigin.y);
bottleSprite.setRotation(bottleModel.getAngle() *   MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);

}
```

The problem in your code seems to be that you don't have a variable named *bottleModelOrigin* atleast it is not visible in your first example.  Although in that case a NullPointerException should have been thrown.